# Is it possible to change the navigation bar height inside a popover to the default height?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

The height of a navigation bar inside a popover is 38px, 
which isn't like the default 44px height. 
Is it possible to change it to the default (44px) height?

The popover is customized using `UIPopoverBackgroundView` which lets me change the popover look totally, except for the navigation bar height.

The app is developed for iOS 5 and above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar is not managed by the popover but by an object further up in the view hierarchiy.

The `UIViewController` which manages your popover has a property `navigationController`. That gives you access to the `UINavigationBar` and you should be able to adjust the height of the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was really inside of navigationController - changing the position of the views inside it.